# How to make a page display different content in vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

I am trying to make an app compiling some of my projects, but it requires a sign-in. However, people can just go to the HTML page with the projects, and I would like to stop this. How do I make sure people cannot access my page without logging in? My code is at this link: https://replit.com/@RAYScript/CodeDay2022

Comment: Bring it from the server dynamically.

Comment: there is nothing you can do with just HTML and JS as it downloads the files to the client side and the client will always be able to see the content of the files. Security requires a server sided solution and a server sided language such as PHP and/or a server sided Framework that is based on Node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a script on server side to manage routes on client side, you can use PHP or Node.js(Base on JavaScript) and start to learn about server.